# Emptying style.less.cache

Tags: less

I just did a migration of a Wordpress site to a new URL - a task I have done many times before.

I have been careful to serialise the DB database with the updated URL, however when I go to the website now I am seeing this error:

> lessphp fatal error: load error: failed to find
>   /homepages/15/d125/htdocs/JM/dev/wp-content/themes/JM/theme/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.lesslessphp
>   fatal error: load error: failed to find
>   /homepages/15/d125/htdocs/JM/dev/wp-content/themes/JM/theme/style.less

I have located a file called **style.less.cache** that contains a reference to the old sites path, can I just delete this? I am assuming this works with [less](http://lesscss.org/), which I have had no experience with up until now.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but if anyone else runs into this issue... delete the file style.less.cache

Be sure to keep the style.less file in place.

The site will regenerate the cache file when it next runs and stop this error from occurring.

Comment: Thank you very much Natacha

Answer (score 0):

The compiler from http://lesscss.org/ has been written in Javascript. I expect your theme use one of the compilers written in php (http://leafo.net/lessphp/ or http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/). It's common practice to cache less files and compile only on file changes.

Empty your cache file should generate a new one cause it is a cache. Only .less should not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure that Disk quota is not exceeded ... otherwise wp-less-cache is not refreshed ... and be sure to have the correct user rights.

Easy ... yes, but often you don't think on such easy things.